# Reading csv file in java and write in new file

Tags: java, string, csv, replace

I am reading a csv file from url, and copy this file to new csv file.

This csv file is `-` separated. I am replacing `-` with `,`.

Reading a large file above 10 mb takes two much time. What can I use for converting `-` separated file to `,` separated file?

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(info.getUrl());
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
Scanner scanner = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    sb.append(line.replace(",", "-").replace("|", ","));
    sb.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: So you want to read the CSV from url and write to a new file?

Comment: Start by checking where the time is spent. It could be that 99% of time is spent reading the file from the remote URL in which case you have to look into your network setup and not the Java code.

Comment: yes Jun Huh and after that load into the database

Comment: @kdowbecki has a good point here, can you try on a file already downloaded and see how long it is?

Comment: By all means get a CSV library. Your simplistic approach may destroy data cause it cannot handle quoting.

Comment: Why do you keep the whole file in memory (`StringBuilder`) when you could just deal with one line at a time?

Comment: @Robert i put header in csv file.in the above the header place code is missing.i place the header in new csv file the and load into the database.

Answer (score 0):

With [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) all you need is this:

```
//configure the input format
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter('-');

//configure the ouput format
CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings();
writerSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter(',');

//use a class for common pre-made routines used for dealing with CSV
CsvRoutines csvRoutines = new CsvRoutines(parserSettings, writerSettings);

//use the `parseAndWrite` method to read the input in a given format and write it back to another.
csvRoutines.parseAndWrite(new FileReader("/path/to/input.csv"), new FileWriter("/path/to/output.csv"));
```

Hope this helps

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Comment: and i want also add the header in that csv

Comment: You can just set the headers on the parser and writer settings. If you need to get the headers from the input, use `setHeaderExtractionEnabled()`

Comment: Length of parsed input (4097) exceeds the maximum number of characters defined in your parser settings (4096). when i parse 30 mb file

Comment: @charujoshi read the exception message. It tells everything you need to do to configure the parser.